# I have a URL with an output that needs to be reformatted and entered back in the browser

Tags: node.js, url, redirect, replace

I have a URL with an output that needs to be reformatted and entered back in the browser.

We have a server that passes caller ID and we can specify a URL to launch with the caller ID included.
IE: googledotcom/search?="{callerID}" . If this is set in the URL manager it would return a google search for "Jackson Steve" when a call is received from Steve Jackson.

**edit: the tag {callerID} that is passed from our server can not be edited in any way because of Asterisk dial plan issues.

This issue is our customer database will only handle name searches in the format of "Jackson, Steve". Without the comma the search comes back empty.

How would I take the name passed from caller ID, create a script to insert a comma and resubmit that URL in the browser?

Basically I need a way to convert "https://www.google.com/#q=name+name" to "https://www.google.com/#q=name,+name" via an automatic script or process. The comma coming after the first name being the change that needs made.

Should this be sent to a website running javascript/html where it formats the caller id name then resubmits or should this somehow be handled by a local script on a computer with something along the lines of autohotkey?

Possibly use some sort of redirect on a web page? send "Name Name" to mywebsiteDOTcom/urlformat/, write a script that would insert a comma in after the first name and redirect the user to myuserdatabaseDOTcom/search?"Name, Name"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces with comma, that should be the easiest solution..

Comment: Yes that would work. The process needs to be automated though. So when a call is received, a browser is launched to our customer database url with the caller ID name submitted in the correct format in the URL, "Name, Name" instead of "Name Name"

Comment: so you are the ones who launch the call right? via your code?

Comment: We specify the URL and include the tag {$callerID} where we want the name.

For instance, say our user database was located at myuserdbDOTcom

We would specify the URL handler to say myuserdbDOTcom/search={$callerID}

So when a call is received a browser window is popped open and that URL is submitted in the browser sending a search to our web based customer database using the caller ID name from the caller.

Comment: pass the tag as {str_replace(" ",",",$callerID)}

Comment: We can't edit the {$callerID} tag because of the Asterisk dial plan in place. That's why we need a way to change the URL that is passed after caller ID has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox, you could write a [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script that is automatically run when you hit the target site (Chrome, I believe has a similar addon named [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/), not sure about IE).  In the javascript, you could examine the URL and either do a straight comma-for-space replacement as Danyal suggested or you could do something a little more elegant with some regex matching, then auto-navigate the browser to the corrected URL.  Once the script was installed, this process would happen automatically.

PS.  What process launches the browser?  Can't you capture the name and the format it before you launch the browser window?  That would seem a much better approach than trying to format it after the fact.